# Application Using WPF and MFC both

Tags: wpf, mfc, device-detection

Sorry for a very vague question but today i was using a software "Samsung Kies" which is developend in WPF but while i ran it as Admin and i  saw an MFC Logo.. and i wondered how did they connect  Native C++ MFC with Managed WPF...

I have never done such kind of integration is that possible or i am thinking it wrong... i am sure they might have used some C++ code to access the device.... it detects an android phone so how is it possible... i dont event know where to start...

So i am posting this question as how is that possible....

Any help and direction would be greatful..... you can Close the Question if its non constructive :)

Comment: @all at leat tell me if its possible or i am wrong .... :(

Comment: a .NET app can access native DLL's using P/Invoke http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services

Comment: @PeskyGnat so how we ill access a device...connected to our system... like a cell phone...

Comment: You'll likely need a driver of some sort, for example, there are a list of drivers here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html

Answer (score 0):

This link gives an example of a MFC/WPF interop, and how to put WPF controls in MFC: http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2010/04/mfc-and-wpf-interop.html . Also, another example, here: http://avaloninmfc.codeplex.com/ . According to the latter, two ways of making it happen are replacing "the standard View with a WPF View" or adding "a WPF control to an MFC dialog box".